# Am I able to switch the Flow within a Process Builder once it is activated?

Tags: visual-workflow

I have a Process Builder in place that uses a Flow to update fields between 2 Objects. Is there a way to change the Flow without scratching the whole Process? I have a new flow which will act on more information and really do not want to delete the whole process. I have tried to clone the process and edit but it wont allow that. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the Process Builder pointing at the same Flow, just a different version of the same Flow API name? Or do you have an old and new Flow, with different API names?

Comment: Old and new. I was able to figure it out after a lot of playing around. I literally deleted the entire action after cloning the process and then added the new flow into a new action. It seems to be working now.